# group List<T> and create new list with count

Tags: c#, linq

I have next class and list:

```
public class cls1
{
  public string prop1 {get; set;}
  public string prop2 {get; set;}
  public string prop3 {get; set;}
}

public List<cls1> list = new List(cls1)();
```

I need to group list by `prop2` field and count this field and on the end order it descending by count.

Comment: What do you mean "count this field"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I meant to count how many of each in field prop2 occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(r => r.prop2)
                .Select(grp => new
                {
                    Key = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Count(),
                })
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Count);
```